# Lemma $2.37$ Adams, Sobolev Space

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

**Theorem.** Let $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$. If $1< p \le 2$ and $q=p/(p-1)$, then

$$\left|\frac{z+w}{2}\right|^q+\left|\frac{z-w}{2}\right|^q \le\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\left|z \right|^p+\frac{1}{2}\left| w\right|^p\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p-1}}$$ There are some small details of the proof of which I am not clear why. I try to explain myself better.

> **Question 1.** What does it mean that since the inequality is symmetric in $z$ and $w$ we can assume that $\left|z\right|\ge \left|w\right|> 0$?

Now, if $w/z=re^{i\theta}$ where $0<r\le 1$ and $0\le \theta <2\pi$, then the above inequality can be rewritten in the form $$\left |\frac{1+re^{i\theta}}{2}\right |^q+ \left|\frac{1-re^{i\theta}}{2}\right |^q\le \bigg(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}r^p\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p-1}}.$$

The following expedient is used for the proof: for $0< r \le 1$, we consider the function $$f(\theta)=\left|1+re^{i\theta}\right|^q+\left|1-re^{i\theta}\right|^q.$$ After a few simple calculations we obtain that: $$f(\theta)=(1+r^2+2r\cos\theta)^{\frac{q}{2}}+(1+r^2-2r\cos\theta)^{\frac{q}{2}}.$$ Since the cosine function is present in the expression of $f$, we have that $$f(2\pi-\theta)=f(\pi-\theta)=f(\theta) $$

> **Question 2.** Why, at this point, is it sufficient to consider the function only in $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) for any pair of complex numbers we have $|z|\geq |w|$ or $|z|\leq |w|$. The symmetry just means that we can treat both cases the same way, so we may as well assume the first one happens (the $|w|>0$ is because the inequality is trivial if one of the terms is zero).

For 2) note that on $[\pi/2,\pi]$ the $\cos$ function takes the same values as in $[0,\pi/2]$, and on $[\pi,2\pi]$ it has the opposite sign, but all that does is switch the first and second terms in the definition of $f$.